# Installing numpy via command line in Windows

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to install numpy to Python through cmd.

My Python file "setup" is in:

```
C:\Users\aviad\Downloads\numpy-1.10.1+mkl-cp27-none-win_amd64 (1)\numpy
```

My python27 folder is in:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 2.7
```

I'm trying to use the following 2 commands, as I saw in YouTube:

1. `cd C:\Users\aviad\Downloads\numpy-1.10.1+mkl-cp27-none-win_amd64 (1)\numpy`
2. `python setup install`

I tried also `python setup.py install`, it says "wrong setup to run"

It says there is no such file or directory even though my cmd recognizes Python and the numpy directory, and I put both locations in "path" (from view advanced settings).

Comment: Those packages are distributed as [wheels](http://pythonwheels.com/) (`.whl`) - they are designed to be installed using `pip` rather than `setup.py`. [See here](https://gehrcke.de/2015/02/how-to-set-up-a-64-bit-version-of-numpy-on-windows/), for example.

Comment: I have trouble installing pip. I go to get-pip.py and it opens some weird long script instead of downloading it.. do you know why?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Have you tried following the instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4750806/1461210)?

Comment: yes, I have tried, and instead of downloading getpip.py, a long script in notepad format appears on the screen.. furthermore, I don't have "scrpits" directory in the python I have downloaded (2.7)

Comment: `get-pip.py` is a Python script - you need to execute it using Python, i.e. `python get-pip.py`. There are step-by-step instructions for installing `pip` in the SO question I linked to in my comment above.

Comment: If you have installed python recently, you probably have a version >= 2.7.9 and thus you already have `pip`. Just try `python -m pip install C:\Users\aviad\Downloads\numpy-1.10.1+mkl-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` and see what you get.

Comment: new problem: using numpy, I want to load my text to g. this is the folder where my py file and txt file are located : 

C:\Users\aviad\Desktop\pythonEx 

now that I have numpy I tried using the following code:
 import numpy as np 
g = np.loadtxt(C:\Users\aviad\Desktop\pythonEx)
 print g 

and run on cmd: 

 cd C:\Users\aviad\Desktop\pythonEx 
 python boolean_conj_predictor.py Training_examples.txt 

why does it not work?